# what does the values in classification_report mean

Tags: python, matrix, random-forest, logistic-regression

I have a problem of classification!
I build 2 models, one with logistic Regression and one with random forest . I tried to print the "classification_report" and i got the two pictures below? 
Which does well in classification ? please ?
The loss function of the model of Random forest is 0.17
The loss function of the model of logistic reg is 0.16

[image: RandomForest]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Precision, Recall and F1 Scores are class specific. Since you have a binary classifier, imagine a confusion matrix as follows
[image]

Then your precision is True Positive / True Positive + False Positive and your Recall is True Positive / True Positive + False Negative. You can read more about it at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

Based on your values, For model 1 is doing better than model 2 except that model 2 corrected some False Negatives at the expense of True Positive.